# React Native multiple file uploader either image or videos

Tags: node.js, react-native, multifile-uploader

Hello everyone i am learning REACT-NATIVE with Node.js , I am looking for the code for multiple file upload either image or video , If anyone know the code please share it .

I did not know where to start and what package will helpful to me .Please mention them .

Answer (score 0):

Some of the packages available are:

[react-native-community/react-native-image-picker](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker)

[ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker)

The first one doesn't support Multiple image selection, the second one does. The first one, however, is a repository by the React Native Community.

Comment: Thank you for the response, what about videos upload second one supports or not

Comment: @Sivasankarchimata, Yes. Its documentation says that it'll support the camera, video, configurable compression, multiple images, and cropping.

Comment: Hello sir can you please refer full tutorial for `react native image crop picker`, Because i din't find any proper tutorial in google github,